# How to apply jobschedular below Lollipop

Tags: android

I created one jobschedular service

```
public class JobSchedularService extends JobService {

    //called when instance is created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("jobservice","oncreate called");
    }

    //called when service instance is destroyed.
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("jobservice","ondestroy called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.e("job start"," called");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.e("job stop","called");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it using jobschedular to schedule a job.
but it only applicable above 21, so what can be applied below api 21?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Answer (score 0):

Use [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) instead, which allows you to schedule tasks and uses Job Scheduler on API21 and above.

Comment: GCM is deprecated, have you even realized that?